# Javascript - Regexp one capital letter per word

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, capitalization

I can't find a way to write regexp with below conditions:

- Only **one capital letter** per word **(not required)** (ideally, if it was the first character)
- Rest of letters must be lowercased

**Example of correct values:**

- John Adam Ben
- Dog cat parrot
- sandwich coffee Biscuit
- feel the difference

**Example of incorrect values:**

- JOHN ADAM BEN
- DoG cat PaRRoT
- SANDWICH cofee Biscuit
- feeL the diFFerence

Is it even possible to write regexp which handles above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Is it even possible to write regexp which handles above?" Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this,,

```
^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|[a-z]+)(?:\s+(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|[a-z]+))*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iD8nZ8/2)

```js
var arr = ["John Adam Ben", "Dog cat parrot", "sandwich coffee Biscuit", "feel the difference", "JOHN ADAM BEN", "DoG cat PaRRoT", "SANDWICH cofee Biscuit", "feeL the diFFerence"];

var regex = /^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|[a-z]+)(?:\s+(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|[a-z]+))*$/g;

var result = {};
arr.forEach(function(str) {
    result[str] = regex.test(str);
    regex.lastIndex = 0;
});

console.log(result);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: I tried your answer and it works.  I'm just wondering if he wants to do a replace with that information?

Comment: we may use the same regex in replace func also. And also I think he wants this regex for validation purpose and he must uses `test` func for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `if` condition , logical not operator `!` ,  `RegExp` `/([A-Z])(?=[A-Z]+)/g` to match uppercase letter followed by uppercase letter , `RegExp.prototype.test()`

```
if (!/([A-Z])(?=[A-Z]+)/g.test(str)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = ["John Adam Ben", "Dog cat parrot", "sandwich coffee Biscuit", "feel the difference", "JOHN ADAM BEN", "DoG cat PaRRoT", "SANDWICH cofee Biscuit", "feeL the diFFerence"];

var regex = /([A-Z])(?=[A-Z]+)/g;

var result = {};
arr.forEach(function(str) {
    result[str] = !regex.test(str);
    regex.lastIndex = 0;
});

console.log(result);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: Failed for `'SANDWICH cofee Biscuit'`

Comment: @Tushar _"Failed for 'SANDWICH cofee Biscuit'"_ `if (!/([A-Z])(?=[A-Z]+)/g.test("SANDWICH cofee Biscuit")) {console.log(true)}`

Comment: Caught by regex `g` flag.

Answer (score 0):

This simple regex should work for you:

```
/^(\b[a-z]*[A-Za-z][a-z]*\b\s*)+$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lE5pG7/1)

```js
var arr = ["John Adam Ben", "Dog cat parrot", "sandwich coffee Biscuit", "feel the difference", "JOHN ADAM BEN", "DoG cat PaRRoT", "SANDWICH cofee Biscuit", "feeL the diFFerence"];

var regex = /^(\b[a-z]*[A-Za-z][a-z]*\b\s*)+$/g;

var result = {};
arr.forEach(function(str) {
    result[str] = regex.test(str);
    regex.lastIndex = 0;
});

console.log(result);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: NP. Actually I was also trying to answer question, _but couldn't find solution :(_, so had code ready. And none of the answer had a demo, so added demo in all answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     var test = ["John Adam Ben",
                 "Dog cat parrot",
                 "sandwich coffee Biscuit",
                 "feel the difference",
                "JOHN ADAM BEN",
                "DoG cat PaRRoT",
                "SANDWICH cofee Biscuit",
                "feeL the diFFerence"
                    ];

     for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
         if (/^(\b[a-z]*[A-Za-z][a-z]*\b\s*)+$/g.test(test[i])) {
             alert(test[i] + "   true")
         }
         else {
             alert(test[i] + "   false")
         }
     }

});
```

Comment: I guess you didn't saw [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34848456/2025923) posted 45 minutes ago

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding this:

- Only one capital letter per word (not required) (ideally, if it was
  the first character)
- Rest of letters must be lowercased

You can find the Incorrect above rules. And here it is:

```
[^b][A-Z]
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/#javascript
It matches these strings:

- JOHN ADAM BEN
- DoG cat PaRRoT
- SANDWICH cofee Biscuit
- feeL the diFFerence